# Play video and sound in python, with RAM cache

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am writing a python application. This application should play a sound or a video when the user press a button.

This are always the same sounds and videos which are played. Each video and each sound may be played several times.

This application will work on a raspberry Pi.

Here is what i have done:

for audio:

```
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("myfile.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

for video:

```
p = Popen(['omxplayer', 'myvideo.mp4'])
```

It works great but the video is not immediatly displayed. This is normal, because the system should load mp4 file on disk and launch external player.

What i want to do is to load all my audio and video files into ram memory and play it immediatly when the user press the button.

I only have 5 videos or audio files, but the users will tap 100 times on the button. As you can understand, i cannot load files on disk each time.

So my question is: how can i load, play and display files from ram memory in python ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> **Comment**: ... there missing a "global media" in playmedia function
>
> There is no `global` required, as there is first a read `media` and therfore Binds to the Local Namespace of `def`. But does not harm.
>
> ```
>     if not filename in media:
> ```
>
> **Comment**: i cannot do twice the section with pygame.mixer ...
>
> Try adding a `seek`.
>
> ```
>     media[filename].seek(0)
>     pygame.mixer.music.load(...
> ```
>
> The buffer is discarded when `music` calls the `close()` method.
>   Then, check if `music` can be forced **NOT TO CLOSE** the Filehandle.

---

This example plays the two Media Files 3 Times, but load File once in Memory:

```
import io, subprocess, time
media = {}
def playMedia(filename):
    if not filename in media:
        with open(filename, 'rb') as in_file:
            media[filename] = io.BytesIO(in_file.read())

    p = subprocess.Popen(['./mplayer', '-cache 8192'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE )
    p.stdin.write(media[filename].getbuffer())
    p.stdin.close()

    time.sleep(5)
    p.terminate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for n in range(3):
        for m in ["mp.mp3", 'mp.mp4']:
            playMedia(m)
```

Comment: Don't you think there missing a "global media" in playmedia function ?

Comment: Second question: i cannot do twice the section with pygame.mixer the load function seems to delete bytesio arguement